# Create Panel data with Google Trend

Tags: python, api, panel-data, google-trends

I am using pytrends package to get data from Google Trend. I want to ask if obtaining panel data from Google Trend is possible, since looking at the package, there are only ways to get data either cross-sectionally or over time.

I think appending the data from the cross-section and the over time options also don't work since for each query the data is normalized, so appending all these normalized data would make my panel data inconsistent, with different normalized scale.

Also, it seems that this always returns me daily data. Is there a way for this to return yearly data?